# Outlook Add-in file reading from mail

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am working on a Outlook add-in. I am not able to use the method item.getAttachmentsAsync in my plugin code to load and read the content of files.
I am getting  ERROR TypeError: item.getAttachmentsAsync is not a function in run time.

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var options = {asyncContext: {currentItem: item}};
item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, this.callback);
```

My requirement is explained below,

In the plugin we have a form and few fields are populated from mail body.
And I need mail attachments to auto upload to Form.

Please suggest a better way to do that.

Comment: Are you in read or compose mode? getAttachmentsAsync is a compose mode only API.

Comment: Oh , I am using it in Read mode,

Comment: Pls suggest any approach for above scenario , I need the inbox mail attachments to plugins form control

Comment: Not sure if you intend to actually send the attachments from the client, or just send the identifiers, and then retrieve them from the server... you can review the properties of the attachments on the client side like this:

Comment: Completing my half thought: You can review the properties of the attachments on the client side by looking at Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.  You can retrieve these attachments from a server following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item (this mentions EWS, I'm sure there is also an equivalent Graph sample somewhere, which would be recommended over EWS).

Comment: You can also try getAttachmentContentAsync API to get attachment content. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: I am getting cors error like below Access to fetch at 'Attachment URL' (redirected from ) from origin 'https://outlook.office365.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using getAttachmentContentAsync I am able to get the file as a blob. but the problem is we need to call this method as soon after the mail opening. otherwise getting cors error

Comment: Are you using Outlook online in a web browser, or are you using the rich native Desktop client?